# Schedule Name not Defined

Tags: python, schedule

I'm very new to this. I'm trying to schedule something. Assuming week[4] = 1

```
week = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday]

if week[4] == 1:
            print("HELLO WORLD")    
            schedule.every().friday.at(startTime).do(lightOn)
            while True:
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(1)

            schedule.every().friday.at(endTime).do(lightOff)
            while True:
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(1)
```

And my light on and light off codes are

```
    def lightOff(self):
        lightY = lightA(light = 0)
        lightOff = lightY.save()
        return lightOff

    def lightOn(self):
        lightX = lightA(light = 1)
        lightOn = lightX.save()
        return lightOn
```

I receive an error "name schedule is not defined". Can someone please point me in the right way?
Yes I did install "pip install schedule"

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Did you import the `schedule` module?

Comment: Even if the `schedule` module is installed, your code needs to import it.

Answer (score 0):

In order your program to recognize schedule you need to:

1. install it using `pip install schedule`
2. import it by `import schedule` on your program begin.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just discovered that i didn't import :)

Comment: you are welcome. The way to thank the helpers and help next users is to upvote good answers + mark the besr answer as such. There are also good comments from pcarter and john.

Comment: apparently i don't have a good reputation yet so my upvote doesn't count? Sorry for that :(